# given 2 endomaps alpha(x) = x+2 and beta(x) = x+3 Prove there is no isomorphism between Z-alpha and Z-beta (Z is set of all integers)

Tags: category-theory

I am working through Conceptual Mathematics (Lawvere/Schanuel) and am stuck on the problem in Session 11/ problem #3 (on pg 159 in my edition).

The problem is:

Given:

$\mathbb Z$ is the set of all integers and  $\mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \alpha}$ 
and $\mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$ 
are the endomaps which add 2 and 3 to their inputs. That is

- ${\alpha}$(x) = x + 2
- ${\beta}$(x) = x + 3

Prove that in the category of sets-with-endomaps  there is no isomorphism between $\mathbb Z^{ \circlearrowleft \alpha}$ 
and $\mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$.

**My attempt at a proof**

In the category of sets with endomaps any map $f$    $ | f: \mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \alpha} \rightarrow  
 \mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$   must obey the law

$$f \circ \alpha  = \beta \circ f$$

So, 
 $$f \circ \alpha(x)  = \beta \circ f(x)$$ 
 $$f(\alpha(x))  = \beta(f(x))$$
 $$f(x+2)  = f(x)+3$$

I need to prove that the last line leads to a contradiction, but at this point I get stuck. I couldn't figure out how to apply proof by induction, and ran into several other dead ends.  Any help would be most gratefully appreciated !
thanks /chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose that $f: \mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \alpha} \rightarrow  
 \mathbb Z^{\circlearrowleft \beta}$ is a morphism. Then $f(0) = a$ and $f(1)=b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Show by induction that $f(2k) = a+3k$ and $f(2k+1)= b + 3k$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Can you see that $f$ can't be surjective? To do so you need to explain why there must be a number $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a - c$ and $b-c$ are not divisible by $3$.

Comment: I can see how to show this for positive integers, but not sure for negative integers?  Is it even needed for all of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: ... but another hint would be appreciated on how to find $c$.

Comment: You only need to find one c. There are three possible remainders upon dividing by three (0,1,2). (This is also true for negative numbers too e,g, $-1=(-1)3+2$) If $r$ and $s$ are the remainders upon diving $a$ and $b$ by $3$, then choose $c$ such that $c$ has a different remainder.

Comment: Ahh, thanks. We just chose a c where both a-c and b-c are not divisible by 3.